# Will I get a refund if I book a flight to China and it's cancelled because of the Coronavirus?

Tags: air-travel, china, refunds, covid-19

I'm supposed to be travelling to China in late April and I'm happy to do so but wonder if the Coronavirus 2019-nCoV continues it's path of destruction and further lock downs and cancellations occur, will I receive a refund from my airline?

I'm going to Zhengzhou which is in a neighbouring province to Hubei (I did Wuhan last year, lucky miss)

Comment: The probability is close to 100%. Not something to worry about.

Comment: @user56513 The probability of airlines going out of business is much larger than 0%.  Therefore, the probability of receiving a refund is substantially smaller than 100%.

Answer (score 1):

If the flight is cancelled, you will for sure have the option to receive a refund. You may also have the option to rebook at a later date without a penalty fee. Note that some airlines will try to give you a voucher rather than a refund, but you can insist on a refund (this is all by law for all flights departing from he EU).

If you booked a package with flights, transfers, hotels, etc. from a travel agent, then the whole package is eligible for a refund (different regulation).

However, if you booked any other things **separately** (hotels, transfers, etc.) they will not be covered (unless they are refundable rates or your have travel insurance covering those).

Comment: Will the law within the UK stay the same once Brexit finally occurs tomorrow?

Comment: @Rob Nothing happens tomorrow other than a few flags being lowered and some people having a bigger than usual hangover Saturday morning. During the transition period (up to the end of the year at least), nearly everything stays exactly the same. The only difference is that the UK has to apply EU law but can't have a say in any changes.

Comment: Just an add-on from personal experience, my flight for early March wasn't even cancelled yet and Swiss Air still refunded me with no penalty when I cancelled, think companies are being very lenient, my hotels in china even refunded me and they were none refundable, guess that's down to the hotel though.

Comment: *If the flight is cancelled, you will for sure have the option to receive a refund* — assuming the company is still in business.